# C# data binding not working for unknown reason

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I wanted to do something really simple with data binding, but this is just not working. this is what i wanted to do:

1, I want to do it with designer, because i don't want to manage the code, which is the whole purpose of me using this IDE.
2, when user edit in a text box, a string variable in my class changes.
3, when the program edit the string variable, text in that text box changes.

here's the code i wrote for it:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged

....

private string _btxtChars;
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public string btxtChars { 
    get 
    { 
        return _btxtChars; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        _btxtChars = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("btxtChars"); 
    } 
}

....

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
```

and I set the corresponding attribute in my designer that have resulted the following code:

```
this.txtCharToAdd.DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", 
        this.frmMainBindingSource, 
        "btxtChars", 
        true, 
        System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    );
```

Now, when I edit the variable btxtchars, nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is `frmMainBindingSource` and how do you assign the `DataSource` property?

Comment: frmMainBindingSource was something created by the IDE, i have no idea why its there.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your BindingSource as follows to initiate binding with your form as data-storage object:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public frmMain() {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        // you can see that the InitializeComponent method contains the following line: 
        // this.frmMainBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(WindowsFormsApplication1.frmMain);

        frmMainBindingSource.DataSource = this; // you should either replace the line above or initiate binding here
    }
//...
```